# Running Flask app in debug mode does not provide the debugger is active or the Debugger PIN on the docker desktop logs

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-desktop, docker-logs

I have been using docker desktop in windows 10 and running the flask application with it. So when I change the python code the docker will auto restart and perform. We can be able to check the logs on the docker desktop's container logs. But now it just shows as below:

```
Serving Flask app "web_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
```

Instead it needs to be

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 139-055-956
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

So that I can be able to check the live logs. Let me know if there is a solution for this to see the live logs with the mentioned details.

Comment: Did you pass ````debug=True```` in ````app.run````

Comment: Yes I have @Advay168